# Filtering rows by date (The last 7 days)

Tags: vba, date, filtering, rows

I want to filter the rows by date.

I want to keep the rows dated today and one week before.

I have modified below code from the other sources however does not work.

My question is how to modify the code for 7 days or 15 days, and how can I simply drop the rows other than my filtering days in the same worksheet rather than copying to another sheet?
I can see the problem is `If TypeName(xVal) = "Date" And (xVal >= Date - 7) Then` but I cannot solve.

Please check the code out below:

```
Sub CopyRowWithCurrentDate()

    Dim xRgS As Range, xRgD As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long, xCol As Long, J As Long
    Dim xVal As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xRgS = Application.InputBox("Select the Date Column:", "Filter On Date", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)

    If xRgS Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xRgD = Application.InputBox("Select a destination cell:", "Filter On Date", , , , , , 8)

    If xRgD Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xCol = xRgS.Rows.Count
    Set xRgS = xRgS(1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    J = 0
    For I = 1 To xCol
        Set xCell = xRgS.Offset(I - 1, 0)
        xVal = xCell.Value

        If TypeName(xVal) = "Date" And (xVal >= Date - 7) Then
            xCell.EntireRow.Copy xRgD.Offset(J, 0)
            J = J + 1
        End If

    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer will focus on the date test. I haven't looked at the other parts of your code.
Replace

```
(xVal >= Date - 7)
```

with

```
(xVal >= Now - 7)
```

and you will get a step closer. There are some minor issues here, since Now will give you today's date with time, making the edge cases somewhat tricky. Also - have a look at the DateDiff function